# How to read JSON file without HTTP Get on Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

I currently I have this way to get a JSON list.

```
function ()
{
    return $http
    (
        {
            url: '../Content/Scripts/Languages/en.json',
            method: "GET",
            headers:
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }
    );
},
```

The reason I don't want to use a GET method is because it works as a promise, and because of that, any function that happens after the promise will execute, and if the list that I retrieve from there is empty will make the app crash.

So what I want is retrieve the list and after that, the rest of my functions can execute with a List filled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use **callback functions** to perform actions in case of **success** or **error**.

Comment: I believe that is a promise... and I'm using those
promise.success
            (
                function (data)
                {
                    $scope.Concepts = data;
                }
            )
            .error
            (
                function (errorMessage)
                {
                    //Something
                }
            );

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) for this.

You will need just this:

```
define('yourModuleWithNgApplication', ['json!path/to/json/file.json'], function (json) {
   // here you can access json variable, it will contain content of file.json
});
```